# Article problem for rsl.cls

Tags: page-breaking, document-classes, journal-publishing

I want to submit an article for Review of Symbolic Logic, and have problems with a failure of pagebreak on the first to second page as illustrated in the following pdf-file [Opostow](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ne6n0jekgpl61u/Oppostow.pdf?dl=0) - notice the bold face sentences on page 1 and 3, and the top sentence on page 2.

Here is  [the archive of tex-files.](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pi3f5lnluacme5f/AAD4Dfv-XtaUbDhGa-s9Cpzza?dl=0) https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pi3f5lnluacme5f/AAD4Dfv-XtaUbDhGa-s9Cpzza?dl=0

Comment: Please make your question self-contained, with the a minimal document showing the issue as part of your question, and a screenshot of the undesired result as image in your question as well. When you do that then people don't need to follow unknown web links (many people don't like/trust external links) but more importantly the question will remain useful for future visitors even if the content in the links changes or is deleted. A link to the class file is ok though, as it is not really possible to put a full class in your question. But please provide the 'official' link [...]

Comment: [...] to the page of the publisher and not a personal Dropbox link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the class `rsl`  (file rsl.cls) uncomment the lines 918 & 919 to

```
 \newenvironment{capsule}
 {\abs@header{\capsulename}\abs@body}
```

[image: class]

Or comment #920.

```
 % !TeX TS-program = pdflatex   
\documentclass[compmod]{rsl}    
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,latexsym, natbib, babel, blindtext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\gridframe{N}
\volume{0}
\issue{0}
\def\fpage{1}
\def\lpage{8}
\pyear{2009}
\pmonth{Month}
\doinu{10.1017/S1755020300000000}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\title[Review of Symbolic Logic]{Document example}

\subtitle{Rejoinders}

\author[F.~A.~B]{F A B}
\affil{University of Somewhere}

\leftrunninghead{FAB}
\rightrunninghead{Document example}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}

XXX

\section{}
\blindtext[3]

%\textbf{Now follows some lines on the first page to illustrate that without using} 
%\begin{verbatim}
%\pagebreak
%\end{verbatim}
%
%\textbf{the first page just continues beyond the page  and} \blindtext 
%
%%\pagebreak 
%
%
%\begin{verbatim}
%after another \pagebreak the document text reappears on the next page:
%\end{verbatim} 

 \blindtext [5]

%\textbf{Notice that the text continued normally to the third page}.    

%\bibliographystyle{rsl}
%\bibliography{Oppostoweber}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Original output, before the "fix".

[image: ori]

Comment: Thanks, that worked very well!